# Cannot read property 'length' of undefined when the inputs are not found on the page

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am getting the dreaded "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined (index):561 window.onload" error, I am getting this on pages where the below input names are not found - as a result its breaking other Jquery that needs to run after this, is there any way I can supress this error and let the other Jquery run?

```
 if ( $("input[name='dnn$ctr621$Form$QTY']").val().length === 0 ) 
 $("input[name='dnn$ctr621$Form$QTY']").val('0');
 if ( $("input[name='dnn$ctr621$Form$QTY2']").val().length === 0 ) 
 $("input[name='dnn$ctr621$Form$QTY2']").val('0');
 if ( $("input[name='dnn$ctr621$Form$QTY3']").val().length === 0 ) 
 $("input[name='dnn$ctr621$Form$QTY3']").val('0');
 if ( $("input[name='dnn$ctr621$Form$QTY4']").val().length === 0 ) 
 $("input[name='dnn$ctr621$Form$QTY4']").val('0');
 if ( $("input[name='dnn$ctr621$Form$QTY5']").val().length === 0 ) 
 $("input[name='dnn$ctr621$Form$QTY5']").val('0');
```

Comment: Check that that input exists before trying to run methods on it?

Comment: Why run stuff on inputs that aren't there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
function setValue(name){
    var field = $("input[name='"+name+"']");
    var value = field.val();
    if (!value ) 
       field .val('0');
}

setValue("dnn$ctr621$Form$QTY");
setValue("dnn$ctr621$Form$QTY2");
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Well you can check that the elements exist:

```
var element = $("input[name='dnn$ctr621$Form$QTY']");    
if (element.val() && element.val().length === 0) {
```

You could also wrap the whole thing in a `try-catch`, but that's not as clean as just checking it first.

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

```
var names = ['dnn$ctr621$Form$QTY', 'dnn$ctr621$Form$QTY2', 'dnn$ctr621$Form$QTY3', ...];

for (var k in names) {
  var name = names[k],
      item = $('input[name="' + name + '"]');

  if ( item.val() ) {
    item.val(0);
  }
}
```

or:

```
$("input[name^='dnn$ctr621$Form$QTY']").each(function(){
  if (!$(this).val()) {
    $(this).val(0);
  }
});
```